# Changing the key of a track without changing the speed of a track

Tags: key

I have two mp3 tracks.

Track1 has a key of A flat major. Track2 has a key of  D minor.

I would like to increase the key of track1 to match the key of track2 without changing the speed of track1 so it won't sound like the vocalist is singing after inhaling helium. If I can get both tracks on the same key, I plan to do a mashup with them with the Mashup2 software.

I also have a Mac with Garage Band in case that software can be used to do the key change.

I tried several online tools but they all left track1 sounding like the vocalist inhaled helium. :-)

Thanks.

Comment: The "helium" effect doesn't mean the online tools are bad - it's a natural by product of pitch shifting up. To avoid it, you need a pitch shifter that can work in terms of formants (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant). I know Melodyne advertises this feature, but I don't know how well it works.

Comment: Another approach you could take would be to get the songs into related keys, rather than the same key.

Comment: You speak/sing higher when breathing helium, so avoiding a speed-up has nothing to do with it -- pitching it higher does it.  [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/download/) is one tool I've used that has time-dependent and -independent pitch shifting, as is Adobe Audition.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Logic Pro X. It has a function which allows you to [transpose audio up or down](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13223?locale=en_US) without altering the speed.

However even if you transpose the Ab major track to D, it's still going to be in a major key. Playing a D major track over a D minor track probably won't sound very good. There is no easy way as far as I know of converting audio in a major key to a minor key.

**EDIT:** Actually you can change the major/minor key of audio using a plugin called [Melodyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melodyne). [Here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voca1OyQdKk) of Bohemian Rhapsody converted to a minor key.

Also as @topo morto pointed out, you could try converting your Ab major track to the relative major key of D minor. In your case this would be F major. It still might sound a bit weird though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I will be ok if the other track is in harmony according to the Camelot Wheel.

Comment: GarageBand on the Mac is “Logic Lite” — I’m 99% sure the feature you are describing is there in the GarageBand for Mac software that Emad-ud-deen already has.

Comment: Hi Everyone. I'm going to try Melodyne.

Answer (score 0):

Either take track A down to F major, or, track B up to F minor. This way, you're in relative keys. Better than trying to dub a major and a minor together.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once using [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) which is open source, it was on a PC but they also have a version for Mac.

I believe you can also do this with [Amazing Slow Downer](https://www.ronimusic.com/) but you have to pay for that one.